# Extracting features with Export Training Data for Deep Learning tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-extraction, deep-learning

The stats file generated from the tool:

```
images = 3400 *3*30*30

features = 6412

features per image = [min = 1, mean = 1,89, max = 10]

classes = 1

cls name cls value images features min size mean size max size

Building 1 3400 6412 0,00 0,00 0,00
```

It is clear that I have 6412 features, but what exactly are these features and what does it mean for there to be a min 1 feature in the image or max 10 features in an image?